# Reopening the 40mph Runners question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question: [Humans can now run 40 mph. How do I keep the stupid people alive?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38590/humans-can-now-run-40-mph-how-do-i-keep-the-stupid-people-alive)

Was closed. I do agree that the question was Too Broad, but the most recent edit, At least I believe, has fixed this problem. While requesting answers with cheap solutions does make certain answer moot, I believe that the question should be reopened, but I am just one man, my opinions may be either wrong or invalid. So, are the edits made sufficient in narrowing the requested answers?

Comment: The question is currently in the reopen review queue.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, it is silly for it to be closed as *too broad* or *opinion* when many good answers exist and a hightvoted accepted answer exists. Whatever issues were worked out in the comments already, or understoon well enough by the answerers.

I nominated it for reopening a week ago and got nothing. Can we discuss this?